BigQuery - Window function without exceeding resource limit
I have a table containing one row per supplier per day, like this:



Supplier
Day




Bob
01/03


Bob
02/03


Bob
03/03



And another table which contains all the payments made by each supplier, like this:



Supplier
Payment amount
Day




Bob
15
02/03


Bob
21
28/03



I need to add a column to the first table showing what was the date of the latest payment, for each supplier for each date. The final output will be just like the first table but adding one field called "latest payment date".
I have tried joining the tables and then filtering to the latest record using a window function, something like this:

SELECT 

supplier,

day,

payment

FROM suppliers LEFT JOIN payments

ON suppliers.supplier = payments.supplier

AND supplier.day >= payments.day

QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY supplier ORDER BY day DESC) = 1

This works for a small dataset, but I need to run it on millions of rows, and it hits the BQ resource limit.
Is there any way around it? I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be much appreciated.

Add a few more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Are all dates always from the same year?

Do you want join column ( last payment date) or ( last payment date, payment_amount)?

Select supplier, day, max(payment) as last_paid
From suppliers LEFT JOIN payments
     ON suppliers.supplier = payments.supplier
        AND supplier.day >= Coalesce(payments.day,'0001-01-01')
Group By supplier, day

You need the Coalesce function to make sure the unpaid billing days records are included in the result.  The comparison to NULL is always False and would defeat the purpose of the Left Join without the Coalesce.

OP wants one row per supplier only (the most recent one). Your query will return one row per day, for each customer.

OP ask the latest payment, for each supplier for each date

Guys, the exact quote from OP was I need to add a column *to the first table* showing what was the date of the latest payment, for each supplier for each date. The final output will be just like the first table but adding one field called "latest payment date".  That's not what you're stating.

You did not say at all about the size of the tables, the number of payments per day for each supplier. Also, if we talk about performance and resources, you need to know the available indexes on the tables.
Therefore, here is a simple example of a query. It is possible to try and compare different variants.
And also look at the execution plans.
See example



Supplier
Day




Bob
2024-03-01


Bob
2024-03-02


Bob
2024-03-03






Supplier
amount
Day




Bob
15
2024-03-02


Bob
21
2024-03-28



SELECT s.supplier,s.day
  ,(select max(day) from payments p 
    where p.supplier=s.supplier and p.day<=s.day) paydate
FROM suppliers s





supplier
day
paydate




Bob
2024-03-01
null


Bob
2024-03-02
2024-03-02


Bob
2024-03-03
2024-03-02



fiddle

Thanks for your answer, I will test this and see if it works!
